# Assumptions about constants in second-order ODE with complex roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

I have a question concerning the derivation for the general solution for a 2nd-order ordinary differential equation with a complex solution. Attached are a snippet of my lecture notes explaining it. My question pertains to its thought processes:

-

[image]

What I find striking about this derivation is that the following condition MUST be met in order for this solution to work:

$$ A + B = \Re$$
$$ A - B = \Im$$

How can this be met simultaneously? An also, doesn't this impose some serious restrictions on what values the constant $C$ and $D$ can take?

Comment: No it does not. Just that $B = A^*$ which still leaves two constants to be determined.

Comment: I think if you would add some initial conditions, say $y(0) = 2, y'(0)=3$ and work out  $A, B, C,$ and $D$, it would clear things up for you.